# How to get a taxonomy term in a custom node.tpl.php file and compare it to a string?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

I am using Drupal 7 and I have a taxonomy term reference in a content type. I am trying to get the value selected in the admin and do a comparison first and then based on the selected value, display the output. Somehow my if condition always fails. How do I get the actual term other than doing print render($content['field_name'] and instead get the term itself. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/7

Comment: I am looking at that. But my concern is that the field in the content type is term reference. and the term reference points to a vocabulary. I am able to get the selected value from the list using print render($content['field_name']) and this gives the value which was selected, but now when I do a string compare, it does not work since its an array and I have no way to get the actual term from that array.

Comment: Can you show us the output of var_dump($content['field_name']); ?

Comment: sure. This is what I get when I do a drupal_set_message.

Comment: I cant see anything, lol

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 80 [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 80 [vid] => 6 [name] => None [description] => [format] => filtered_html [weight] => 0 [vocabulary_machine_name] => writers [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => Array ( [0] => skos:Concept ) [name] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => rdfs:label [1] => skos:prefLabel ) ) [description] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => skos:definition ) ) [vid] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => skos:inScheme ) [type] => rel ) [parent] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => skos:broader ) [type] => rel ) ))))

Comment: and you want to compare the name of that vocab for which its referencing to, right?

Comment: The name here is None and this is the selected value. I want to compare this selected value to a string "None".

Comment: give this a shot taxonomy_term_load($tid);

Comment: nope not working. From what I observe, if I do a $writer = (string)render($content['field_writer']); then it is 188 characters long and this is due to the fact that it takes its own div tags and hence it is this long. I have no clue as to how do I just get None which I should ideally get using $content['field_writer'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name but sadly this is not working.